# How to check if date is less than or equals to today's date?

Tags: c#

I need to determined if the date entered by the user is less than or equals to today's date.

I have the following code which converts the dates to `int` and than compare their values. Is there a more efficient or lean way to get this accomplished with less lines of code?

How do I do this with far less code or extraneity?

Code:

```
class Program
{
    public static bool IsDateBeforeOrToday(string input)
    {
        bool result = true;

        if(input != null)
        {
            DateTime dTCurrent = DateTime.Now;
            int currentDateValues = Convert.ToInt32(dTCurrent.ToString("MMddyyyy"));
            int inputDateValues = Convert.ToInt32(input.Replace("/", ""));

            result = inputDateValues <= currentDateValues;
        }
        else
        {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsDateBeforeOrToday("03/26/2015"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you really asking how to convert the string to a date so you can check it? `Convert.ToDateTime(input)`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Instead of converting current date to string and then `int` and doing the comparison, convert your parameter date string to `DateTime` object and then compare like:

```
var parameterDate = DateTime.ParseExact("03/26/2015", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var todaysDate = DateTime.Today;

if(parameterDate < todaysDate)
{
}
```

You can have your method as:

```
public static bool IsDateBeforeOrToday(string input)
{
    DateTime pDate;
    if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out pDate))
    {
        //Invalid date
        //log , show error
        return false;
    }
    return DateTime.Today <= pDate;
}
```

- Use `DateTime.TryParseExact` if you want to avoid exception in
  parsing.
- Use `DateTime.Today` if you only want to compare date and ignore the
  time part.

Comment: @Habib, thanks. These responses are certainly better than the solution I designed, which is why I ask the question, in a effort to code or make things better.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [DateTime.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx) method. You could do this:

```
DateTime dTCurrent = DateTime.Now;
DateTime inputDate = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

int result = DateTime.Compare(dTCurrent, inputDate);
```

The int 'result' would indicate if dTCurrent is less than inputDate (less than 0), same as (0) or greater than (greater than 0).

Answer (score 3):

You could use `TryParse` of `TryParseExact` which returns `bool`, whether parse succeeded or not.

In my first implementation I threw exception, but it is useless, because `Parse` or `ParseExact` will throw it automatically if fails. So there is two options:

- Just use `Parse` and catch exceptions in `Main()`;
- Use `TryParse` and do something useful in `IsDateBeforeOrToday()` if input is wrong.

Implementation:

```
class Program
{
    public static bool IsDateBeforeOrToday(string input)
    {
        DateTime inputTime;
        var parseResult = DateTime.TryParse(input, inputTime);
        if (!parseResult)
            //Do something useful if parse failed.
        return inputTime <= DateTime.Now
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsDateBeforeOrToday("03/26/2015"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to throw an exception if TryParse fails, why not just use Parse instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.Compare()` If Result is less than that means first date is less than second and 0 means equal and greater

```
DateTime dileverydate = Convert.ToDateTime(dileveryDate.Text);
var todaysDate = DateTime.Today;
int result = DateTime.Compare(dileverydate, todaysDate);
```

Comment: How is this different from [this answer from more than 3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29258367/215552)?